# java Element.setTextContent drops newlines

Tags: java, xml

I have a problem with creating an xml file.  I need to preserve the newlines in a sting retrieved from a database and stored into a node.  I haven't been able to get it to work.  I've tried the following variations.

```
Element ele = doc.createElement("productDescription");
ele.setTextContent(text); // this drops the newlines.
ele.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(text)); // this drops the newlines.
ele.setTextContent(text.replace("\n", "&#10;")); // this changes all the newlines to the text "&#10;"
```

I'm outputting the document with.

```
String QueryResults(String query) {
  Document doc = CreateDoc(query);
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
  try {
    docTransformer.transform(source, result);
  } catch (TransformerException ex) {
    System.out.println("Failed to convert doc to string: " + ex.getMessage());
    return null;
  }
  return sw.toString();
}
```

A sample of the output would be.

```
<result>
  <Orders>
    <productName>Widget thingy</productName>
    <productDescription>A really cool widget thingy.\nReally, its cool.</productDescription>
  </Orders>
</result>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this way :

```
ele.setTextContent(text.replace("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator")));
```

Comment: didn't help but I found the real problem.

Comment: I found the problem.  It wasn't with the document it was with the http server response.

    Headers hdr = exchange.getResponseHeaders();
    //hdr.set("Content-Type", "application/xhtml+xml"); /*this was wrong*/
    hdr.set("Content-Type", "application/xml"); /*this works*/
    exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());

I was testing the results by issuing a query form a web browser then copy and pasting from the web browser.  So it was the browser dropping the newlines.

Comment: marking this as answer because I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question :(